# Update Open Date Based Send Open Time

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I currently have a salesforce query that updates a customers last open date if they opened the previous day. I would like to add a stipulation to this that says 'OpenTime cannot equal SendTime if they have the same EmailName (or JobID)'

Also is there a way to make sure it looks at open and send time down to the minute? Not just the day?

Current query:

```sql
select max(a.eventdate) as last_open, b.email
from (
    select subscriberkey, eventdate
    from _open
    where datediff(dd, eventdate, getdate()) <= 1
) a 
inner join Purchase b
on b.subscriberkey = a.subscriberkey
group by b.email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% what you mean by "Also is there a way to make sure it looks at open and send time down to the minute".

But this is what I have. Similar to your query but there is a Where statement in the subquery that will drop any EDM send that has an open time and send time within 10 minutes of one another, is this sort of what you meant by "down to the minute". You can adjust the time window by manipulating the -5,5 characters. You wont need to add a Where statement to cover the "have the same EmailName (or JobID)" part of your post as the LEFT JOIN on _Sent already does this.

There is also a Dedupe section that will dudupe at a subscriberkey level and order by newest Open date to oldest (this will select the latest open date).

I am not sure if this answers your question but hopefully it can help.

Please test this out as I have not had a chance to.

```
  SELECT 
    a.[eventdate] AS [last_open],
    b.[email]
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            o.[subscriberkey], 
            o.[eventdate],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.[subscriberkey] ORDER BY o.[eventdate] DESC) AS [RN]
        FROM _open o
        LEFT JOIN _Sent s
        ON s.[JobId] = o.[JobId]
        WHERE 
        DATEDIFF(DD, o.[eventdate], GETDATE()) < = 1 
        /*ensure open and send date is not with 10 minutes of one another*/
        AND o.[eventdate] NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(mi,-5,s.[eventdate]) AND  
         DATEADD(mi,5,s.[eventdate])
         ) AS a
   LEFT JOIN [Purchase] b
   ON b.[subscriberkey] = a.[subscriberkey]
   WHERE 
   [RN] = 1
   AND b.[subscriberkey] IS NOT NULL
```

If you are having time out issues with that query, I would recommend to split it out into 2 Query activities. See below:

Query Activity 1.
Target DE (eg): "Purchase_Opens_1", Data Action OVERWRITE

```
         SELECT 
            o.[subscriberkey], 
            o.[eventdate]
        FROM _open o
        LEFT JOIN _Sent s
        ON s.[JobId] = o.[JobId]
        WHERE 
        DATEDIFF(DD, o.[eventdate], GETDATE()) < = 1 
        /*ensure open and send date is not with 10 minutes of one another*/
        AND o.[eventdate] NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(mi,-5,s.[eventdate]) AND  
         DATEADD(mi,5,s.[eventdate])
```

Query Activity 2.
Target DE (eg): "Purchase_Opens_Updates_2" If final query then Data Action UPDATE, if second last query then Data Action OVERWRITE

```
SELECT 
    SQ.[last_open],
    SQ.[email]
FROM (
 SELECT 
    a.[eventdate] AS [last_open],
    b.[email],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.[subscriberkey] ORDER BY o.[eventdate] DESC) AS [RN]
FROM [Purchase_Opens_1]  a
   LEFT JOIN [Purchase] b
   ON b.[subscriberkey] = a.[subscriberkey]
   WHERE 
   [RN] = 1
   AND b.[subscriberkey] IS NOT NULL
   ) AS SQ 
WHERE 
[RN] = 1
```

If Primary Key Violation, here is Query Activity 3 (you can roll Query 2 and 3 into one if you don't have timeout issues which you should not).
Target DE (eg): "Purchase_Opens_Updates_3", Data Action UPDATE

```
SELECT 
    SQ.[last_open],
    SQ.[email]
FROM (
 SELECT 
    a.[last_open],
    a.[email]
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[email] *if this if your PK* ORDER BY a.[last_open] DESC) AS [RN]
FROM [Purchase_Opens_Updates_2]  a
   ) AS SQ 
WHERE 
[RN] = 1
```

Comment: Hey - the syntax of the query works but it keeps timing out. Any ideas on how to simplify the query? Or should I split up into two queries?

Comment: Hey Hailee

To optimise the query, the first thing I'd do would be to get rid of the INNER JOIN and move it to a LEFT JOIN. LEFT JOINs are processed fast by the system than INNER JOINs. 

It would be this: 
   INNER JOIN [Purchase] b
   ON b.[subscriberkey] = a.[subscriberkey]
   WHERE 
   [RN] = 1

To this: 
   LEFT JOIN [Purchase] b
   ON b.[subscriberkey] = a.[subscriberkey]
   WHERE 
   [RN] = 1
  AND b.[subscriberkey]  IS NOT NULL

Comment: Hi Hailee, I have updated my answer with the LEFT JOIN as explained above and also a solution that splits out the large query into two separate query activities. Please let me know if you need any more assistance.

Comment: Hi @HaileeMarcinek 
Just wondering if this worked? Let me know if you need me to look into it further, 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an error on the first query now: Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Comment: Hi @HaileeMarcinek, what are the primary keys for your target DE?

Comment: Hi @HaileeMarcinek, If you are still having the Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint you will have to delete duplicates at your primary key level. I have adjusted my answer above to cover this. Please have a look.